# If $p$ is prime and $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand why a line in the following proof is true. Suppose $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. If $p$ does not divide $a$, then $a$ and $p$ are coprime, and so there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+py=1$. Then we have $abx+pby=b$ and $pby=b-abx$. Hence $p|b-abx$.

Now, the next line in the proof says that this implies that $p|b$. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b=abx+(b-abx)$, both summands divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip the "and" at the end of the proof. Since $p | ab$ we have $ab = pm$ for some $m$. Then
$$
b = abx + pby = pmx + pby = p(mx+by)
$$
so $p | b$.

Comment: Maybe of interest :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write it like this:

> Suppose that $p\mid ab$, and without loss of generality, that $p\nmid a$. Then, by [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), $$(p,a)=1=ua+vp$$ for some $u,v\in\Bbb Z$. Thus, $b=uab+vpb$, and so $p\mid b$.

In your particular case, however, if $p|b-abx$, then by definition $$b-abx=pn,$$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$ and moreover, $$\frac{b-abx}{p}\in\Bbb Z.$$ Thus we *must* have that $p\mid b$ and $p\mid abx$. The latter of these statements, though, is guaranteed by hypothesis (remember $p\mid ab$) so we conclude $p\mid b$.